# What is wrong with the sentence ''Only you and him can do this work fast."?

Tags: nouns

I came across it through a study note provided in a reference book but couldn't find what makes this sentence wrong as the answers were not provided in the book.
I am more interested to know about the concept behind the sentence correction.

Comment: If you remove "you and" from the sentence, how should it read?

Comment: @Mick wouldn't that be a different sentence from the one I asked?

Comment: @user2768 him is referring to other person who cannot be "I". The purpose is not to replace the person the sentence is referring to for the sake of its correction.

Answer (score 1):

See ELU's answer **[here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/358552/210913)**, which discusses the issue, probably more acutely and accurately than you'll find in 99% of other places, including ELU and ELL answers. If your question hadn't been transferred it could have been marked as a duplicate.

Basically, the answer is "it depends on what you mean by wrong". If you are talking about prescriptive grammar it's "wrong"  because it needs to be *you and he* because that is the subject of the sentence. However, as the answer I linked to shows, it is not necessarily "wrong" according to natural grammar. Some linguists have started using the terminology *informal (but standard)  English* to cover this situation. Basically,  you need to choose your grammar, and what informs that is often *who do I wish to please*, or *am I expected to use formal English forms here*? If you want to write in a form that will please most prescriptive grammarians, use *you and he*. But that's not your only option.

Answer (score 0):

only you and HE can do this work fast.
you need subject+verb (you can / he can - do this work fast)